# undo changes to value of receive.denyCurrentBranch in git config

Tags: git, version-control, repository, git-config

When trying to push to a non-bare repository, it mentions making a change to the config for receive.denyCurrentBranch
What is the statement to undo this (or the default value of it receive.denyCurrentBranch)?

```
git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git being git, there are many ways to do this.

To set the same value as the default, consult [its documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) to see what the default action is:

```
$ git help config
```

and then search for `receive.denyCurrentBranch`:

> If set to true or "refuse", git-receive-pack will deny a ref update to the currently checked out branch of a non-bare repository. Such a push is potentially dangerous because it brings the HEAD out of sync with the index and working tree. If set to "warn", print a warning of such a push to stderr, but allow the push to proceed. If set to false or "ignore", allow such pushes with no message. Defaults to "refuse".

Thus, you can set it to `refuse` to make it act the way it would if it were unset.:

```
$ git config receive.denyCurrentBranch refuse
```

Of course, you can also simply unset it:

```
$ git config --unset receive.denyCurrentBranch
```

This leaves the `receive` section in the config even if it's empty, but that's harmless.  However, if you prefer, you can remove the section with `git config --remove-section`, or you can open the entire configuration in your configured editor with `git config --edit`, and update or delete it however you like.